# Dataflow appears to be stuck 3

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I got this error on Dataflow log:

> (11b55950300ec4ce): Workflow failed. Causes: (11b55950300ec459): The
>   Dataflow appears to be stuck. Please reach out to the Dataflow team at
>   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-dataflow.

The JobID is: `2017-11-13_20_58_16-5812097262489045871`

I tried the exact same code and it is working on other project...

Any help is appreciated,

Yosua

Comment: I tried the WordCount code and it got the same error on the same project.

Error id: `(efbac2f6c2ec13f0)`

JobID: `2017-11-14_00_42_11-4211727424575330420`

Comment: It looks like Dataflow failed while trying to start GCE VMs to run the job. Is it possible that you renamed the default network ? If so you have to specify the network using pipeline option https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/options/DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions.java#L149

Comment: @chamikara Yeah, it seems to be the network problem. It works after I specify the network in the pipeline option. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns the dataflow cannot spawn workers because of mismatch between the default network's region (in `asia-southeast1` in my case) and the zone parameters (default: `us-central1-f`).

So to solve this issue I need to explicitly set the `network`, `subnet`, and `zone` i the pipeline parameter.

Note: I found this unintuitive but it is okay to have `region` as `us-central1` and zone outside `us-central1` since the `region` parameter is where we deploy the jobs and `zone` is where we spawn the worker.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params